# Find a character from a string without using find method?

Tags: python, string

As I am a newbie ...  not understanding why it's not working properly ?
expecting  the cause and solution and also tips
thanks

```
str = "gram chara oi ranga matir poth"
find ='p'
l = len(str)
for x in range(0,l):
    if str[x]==find:         
        flag = x
        #break
if flag == x:
    print "found in index no",flag
else:
    print "not found in there"
```

Comment: `try: print str.index(find);except: print "Not Found";`

Comment: @JoranBeasley 
thanks..... its new (try:except:) for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if flag == x` looks strange. What value of `x` are you expecting there?

I'd suggest instead initializing `flag` to `None` and then checking for it not being `None` at the end of the loop.

```
flag = None # assign a "sentinel" value here
str = "gram chara oi ranga matir poth"
find = 'p'
for x in range(len(str)):
    if str[x] == find:         
        flag = x
        # Leaving out the break is also fine. It means you'll print the
        # index of the last occurrence of the character rather than the first.
        break
if flag is not None:
    print "found in index no", flag
else:
    print "not found in there"
```

Comment: thanks,
my intention was that  if  `str[x] == find` then save the index in `flag`
my mistake was ....... the value of x is changing..in for loop

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to have flag be the location of the index of the (first) matching character. Good!

```
if str[x]==find:
  flag = x
  break
```

But how to tell if nothing was found?  Testing against x won't help!  Try initializing flag to a testable value:

```
flag = -1
for x in range(0,l):
    if str[x]==find:         
        flag = x
        break
```

Now everything is easy:

```
if flag != -1:
    print "found in index no",flag
else:
    print "not found in there"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method of searching is valid (iterating through the characters in the string).  However, your problem is at the end when you're evaluating whether or not you've found the character.  You're comparing `flag` to `x`, but when you do the comparison, `x` is [out of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/1368616).  Because `x` is declared in a for loop statement, it's only defined *inside* that for loop.  So, to fix your code set an initial value for `flag` that you can check against, then change the check at the end:

```
flag = None
for x in range(len(str)):
    if str[x] == find:         
        flag = x
        break  # Using break here means you'll find the FIRST occurrence of find 

if flag:
    print "found in index no",flag
else:
    print "not found in there"
```